# CAShapeLayer strokeColor get mix with fillColor

Tags: ios7, quartz-core, cashapelayer

I have made a hexagonal View with border. The problem I am facing now is I am not able to set the desired color for border which I have made using strokeWidth (not borderWidth) and now my layer's strokeColor get mix with fill color of the layer.

Here is the code:

```
CAShapeLayer *hexagonMask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CAShapeLayer *hexagonBorder = [CAShapeLayer layer];
hexagonMask.frame=self.layer.bounds;
hexagonBorder.frame = self.layer.bounds;

UIBezierPath* hexagonPath=[self makeHexagonalMaskPathWithSquareSide:side];     //making hexagon path

hexagonMask.path = hexagonPath.CGPath;                 //setting the mask path for hexagon
hexagonBorder.path = hexagonPath.CGPath;               //setting the maskpath for hexagon border
hexagonBorder.fillColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor; //setting by default color

hexagonBorder.lineWidth = self.customBorderWidth; //   setting border width

hexagonBorder.strokeColor = self.customBorderColor.CGColor;  //setting  color for hexagon border 

hexagonBorder.fillColor = self.customFillColor.CGColor;    //setting fill color for hexagon
```

Any suggestions to solve this Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way out to solve this problem.
I have added a CALayer as sublayer and the fill color is used to create as a UIImage which is used to set as contents for the sublayer.
Here is the code for someone who may face this problem in future

```
CAShapeLayer *hexagonMask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CAShapeLayer *hexagonBorder = [CAShapeLayer layer];
hexagonMask.frame=self.layer.bounds;
hexagonBorder.frame = self.layer.bounds;

UIBezierPath* hexagonPath=[self makeHexagonalMaskPathWithSquareSide:side];       //making hexagon path

hexagonMask.path = hexagonPath.CGPath;                 //setting the mask path for   hexagon
hexagonBorder.path = hexagonPath.CGPath;               //setting the maskpath for hexagon border
hexagonBorder.fillColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor; //setting by default color

hexagonBorder.lineWidth = self.customBorderWidth; //   setting border width

hexagonBorder.strokeColor = self.customBorderColor.CGColor;  //setting  color for hexagon border 


CGFloat coverImageSide=side-(_customBorderWidth);
            CGFloat backgroundLayerXY=_customBorderWidth/2.0;

            UIImage *coverImage=[UIImage ImageWithColor:_customFillColor width:coverImageSide height:coverImageSide];
            UIBezierPath* dpath=[self makeHexagonalMaskPathWithSquareSide:coverImageSide];


            CALayer *backgroundLayer=[CALayer layer];
            backgroundLayer.frame=CGRectMake(backgroundLayerXY, backgroundLayerXY, coverImageSide, coverImageSide);
            CAShapeLayer *backgroundMaskLayer=[CAShapeLayer layer];
            backgroundMaskLayer.path=dpath.CGPath;
            backgroundLayer.mask=backgroundMaskLayer;
            [backgroundLayer setContentsScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
            [backgroundLayer setContentsGravity:kCAGravityResizeAspectFill];
            [backgroundLayer setContents:(__bridge id)[UIImage maskImage:coverImage toPath:dpath].CGImage];

            [self.layer.sublayers[0] addSublayer:backgroundLayer];
```